# Circular interpolation for Matplotlib imshow with cyclic color maps

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

How would you implement a cyclic interpolation method to be used with the matplotlib.pyplot.imshow function?

When the imshow-function is utilized for visualizing data with cyclical nature, such as the times of the 24 hour clock, the cyclical color maps are quite useful. However, if the imshow is used to upscale the data using interpolation, the plots don't come out as one would expect.

See below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colormap = plt.cm.twilight_shifted

# Create an array with values between 0-3
arr = np.random.randint(0,4,size=[16,16])

# Create a smaller array with values between 20-23
patch = np.random.randint(20,24,size=[4,4])

# Insert the patch in the middle of the array
arr[6:10,6:10] = patch

# Visualize the array, without interpolation
plt.figure(figsize=[18,10])
plt.imshow(arr, cmap = colormap, aspect='auto', interpolation=None)
plt.colorbar()

# Visualize the array, with interpolation
plt.figure(figsize=[18,10])
plt.imshow(arr, cmap = colormap, aspect='auto', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.colorbar()
```

Results in two plots:

[No interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI8g5.png)
[Bicubic interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdFv1.png)

You can see that the interpolation creates a white line between the two groups of values, corresponding to values around 12. However, since we are utilizing a cyclic color map, I would actually expect the values interpolated between the [0,3] and [20,23] groups to be black. I assume this is because the interpolation methods implemented in the imshow function don't account for the cyclicity of the color map.

Any ideas on how to achieve proper interpolation for the visualization? Should cyclic interpolation for cyclic colormaps be added to matplotlib as a feature?

Comment: `> Should cyclic interpolation for cyclic colormaps be added to matplotlib as a feature?` I think such a feature would always run into inconsistencies when adjacent values are exactly on opposite sides of the "circle". How would the program know in which direction to interpolate when the two points are equally far apart in both directions?

Comment: Even if neighbouring points are only approximately equally far apart in both directions, you could easily run into local inconsistencies. Imagine three neighbouring pixels A, B, C arranged as an L shape. A and B are close in value; A is slightly less than half a circle away from C. B is slightly more than half a circle apart from C. The interpolated subpixels between A and C will be on the opposite side of the colour map from the interpolated subpixels between B and C, and the interpolated colours will not be locally smooth (which is the point of the interpolation to begin with).

Comment: It's true that the case you point out would be an issue to solve. However, the current situation where the user has no control at all over the direction of interpolation isn't optimal either. I think many users don't even realise that the interpolation isn't working very intuitively with the cyclic maps, leading to inconsistencies in the plot results.

Comment: Your example is very illustrating. Perhaps this could be addressed by raising a warning in the imshow code if cyclic color maps are used with interpolation.

Comment: I am not sure this issue has a solution but I am not a matplotlib maintainer. If you want to pursue this issue and maybe implement such a feature then I would start a conversation with the maintainers by either raising an issue on github or talk to them on their [gitter](https://gitter.im/matplotlib/matplotlib). In my experience, they are a very nice bunch and very responsive on either platform.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your input.